# Could not find the right regex pattern

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I want to write a regular expression to match every word which :

- Does not start with any of these 2 strings (TEMP_, TMP_)
- Contains in the middle the string : LME999
- Does not end with any of these 2 strings (.flag, _TEMP)
- Before and After LME999, the string can have any alphanumeric character

I wrote this regular expression, but it does not work as expected

```
(?!TEMP_)+(?!TMP_)+(\w)+LME999+(\w)+((?!.flag)(?!_TEMP))
```

Here are some valid string: 
StringLME999String

Comment: `•Before and After LME46` is this a typo?

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!TE?MP_).*?LME999.*$(?<!\.flag|_TEMP)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ0aG1/6)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^                   # line start
(?!TE?MP_)          # negative lookahead to assert failure if starts with TMP_ or TEMP_
.*?                 # match 0 or more of any char (lazy)
LME999              # match LME99
.*                  # match 0 or more of any char 
$                   # line end
(?<!\.flag|_TEMP)   # negative lookbehind to assert failure if ends with .flag or _TEMP
```